# jquery mobile doesn't interpret my inserted code with .html()

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, jquery-mobile, click

when I change the content in my page using `click()` and than `html()`, jquery mobile doesn't change the view of the inserted code, in this case a listview.

I build a shortened example to show what I mean:

http://jsfiddle.net/eTz8H/

When you use the `Suchen` button it insert the  list, but it don't looks like the jquery mobile listview.

**JS:**

```
function searchSeries(){
    list = '<ul id="seriesResultList" data-role="listview" style="margin-top: 2em;" data-inset="true"><li><a href="#"><img src="http://www.tvdb.info/gfx/v/v20703.gif"><h2>Vegas</h2><p>USA 2012–</p></a></li></ul>';
    $("#searchResult").html(list);
}

$(document).ready(function() {
    $("#submit").click(function(){
        searchSeries();
    });
});
```

**HTML**

```
<form class="ui-body ui-body-a" id="seriesNew" action="index.php?site=autoseriesNew" method="post" style="padding-bottom: 2em;">
    <label for="newSerie">Serie:</label>
    <input type="search" name="newSerie" id="newSerie" value="">
    <button class="ui-shadow ui-btn ui-corner-all" type="submit" id="submit">Suchen</button>
</form>
<div id="searchResult">
</div>
```

Comment: Works fine here. What browser are you using?

Comment: `e.preventDefault();` may be required to stop the form `submit` *( if that is what you want )* - check - http://jsfiddle.net/6ANvb/1/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You will need to trigger 'create' event for making dynamic HTML jQM-ish.

You can try with the following,

```
$("#searchResult").trigger('create')
```

or if it doesn't work,

```
$(".ui-page").trigger('create')
```

on the page containing this element.